# Why do the limits of integration change when finding the surface area of the curve rotated about the y-axis?

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

The given curve is rotated about the y-axis. Find the area of the resulting surface.

$\sqrt[3]{x^2}+\sqrt[3]{y^2}=1     , 0\leq y \leq1 $

[image]

We set up the surface area integral:

$\int_{-1}^{1} 2\pi x ds$

I understand how to find the arc-length(ds) and set up the integral but why wouldn't out limits stay from 0 to 1? My reasoning is that $2\pi x$
 is taking in account that our radius from 0 to 1 should be doubled. Shouldn't we only care about the arc-length from 0 to 1?

For instance if we were to find the surface area of $y=1/3 \sqrt[2]{x^3}+$ ,  $0\leq y \leq12$ rotating about the y-axis, our integral would be,

$\int_{0}^{12} 2\pi y ds$

[image]

Comment: Yes, it should be $\int_0^1 2\pi x\,dx$. Besides the integral you stated $\int_{-1}^1 2\pi x\,ds$ is zero due to the symmetry in $x$.

Comment: It is easier to calucalte the revolution area of this [astroid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astroid) if you use the [parametric formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_of_revolution#Area_formula).